# Dynamically naming edited csv, to include part of the old csv name

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I am using some code to merge two csvs and sort these by two columns. Ouputting a new csv.
The input csvs are of the same name just numbered 1 & 2. I am repeating this code for multiple sets of data. I was wondering what the method would be to make the code output a file name containing the first part of the original file names.

My current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("data csv 1\September 2013 1 UUedit1.csv", delimiter = ",")
df2 = pd.read_csv("data csv 1\September 2013 2 UUedit2.csv", delimiter = ",")
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="Unique Element")
delcols = "Element_y", "number_y", "date_y", "title_y", "name_y"

for delcol in delcols:
    del merged[delcol]
    
merged.rename(columns={"name_x": "name", "rdate_x": "date", "title_x": "title", "number_x": "number", "Element_x": "Element"}, inplace = True)
merged = merged.sort("Element").reset_index(drop=True)
merged = merged.sort("date").reset_index(drop=True)
merged.to_csv("MRG.csv", index=False, sep = ",")
```

So in this example both the input files are called `September 2013`"number""UUedit" I want to make my code output the file name directly as `September 2013 MRG.csv` how can this be coded? To clarify if the two original files were `October 2013` then the output would be `October 2013 MRG.csv`
Many thanks GTPE

### Edit

Upon running the code supplied by Christian Ternus
I received the following print and traceback:

```
Usage: C:/Test.py <month> <year>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    month, year = sys.argv[1:]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I am unsure what the second variable should be set to.
Many thanks
GTPE

#### Edit 2

I managed to get the code to work by calling it CMD, however my attempts at calling the script through python didn't seem to work. I tried the folowing:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'RawDataSheetMergerPandasTest.py September 2013'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: Well, you're hardcoding the original filenames. As long as you're doing that, it doesn't make sense to automatically process the filenames to get the output filename -- you might as well just hardcode it too.

Comment: Yeh I kind of understand that, what method would we use to not hardcode the import file names, this could be equally useful to me as the original question. Possibly killing two birds with a singular dynamic stone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to get the name of the next month, given the name of the current month:

```
import calendar
nextmonth = calendar.month_name[1:][(calendar.month_name[1:].index(month) + 1) % 12]
```

And here's that same logic applied to your script, with a few other improvements :) Run this script as "`./myscript.py somemonth someyear`". It'll output a CSV file named `nextmonth year MRG.csv`, even taking into account localization and wrapping the year properly.

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage: {0} <month> <year>".format(sys.argv[0])
month, year = sys.argv[1:]

if not month in calendar.month_name:
    print "Invalid month! Month must be one of:{0}".format(str(calendar.month_name))
if not year.isdigit():
    print "Invalid year! Year must be a number."

nextmonth = calendar.month_name[1:][(calendar.month_name[1:].index(month) + 1) % 12]

df1 = pd.read_csv("data csv 1\{0} {1} 1 UUedit1.csv".format(month, year), delimiter = ",")
df2 = pd.read_csv("data csv 1\{0} {1} 2 UUedit2.csv".format(month, year), delimiter = ",")
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="Unique Element")
delcols = "Element_y", "number_y", "date_y", "title_y", "name_y"

for delcol in delcols:
    del merged[delcol]

merged.rename(columns={"name_x": "name", "rdate_x": "date", "title_x": "title", "number_x": "number", "Element_x": "Element"}, inplace = True)
merged = merged.sort("Element").reset_index(drop=True)
merged = merged.sort("date").reset_index(drop=True)

if month == calendar.month_name[-1]: year = str(int(year + 1))

merged.to_csv("{0} {1} MRG.csv".format(nextmonth, year), index=False, sep = ",")
```

If you don't need the next-month feature (sounds like you actually don't), take out these two lines:

```
nextmonth = calendar.month_name[1:][(calendar.month_name[1:].index(month) + 1) % 12]
[...]
if month == calendar.month_name[-1]: year = str(int(year + 1))
```

and replace the last line with:

```
merged.to_csv("{0} {1} MRG.csv".format(month, year), index=False, sep = ",")
```

Comment: Not conventional stackoverflow, but I think I love you. Will be playing around with this for a while :)

Comment: p.s. upvote is just for taking time out your day to answer it, will mark accepted once tested.

Comment: You're welcome! If you really want to thank me, look up the functions I'm using there and figure out how each of those things is implemented, play around with them and apply it in your own code :)

Comment: Will do :) I have a feeling the methods used here will be repeated for multiple other scripts I have :)

Comment: I was a hello worlder 2 or so months ago, I dont love coding (yet), but I love the automation it can achieve for me :)

Comment: I have tested now, apologies for the delay on this. I have added the trackback to the bottom of my OP, Many thanks

Comment: You need to run it on the command line with <month> and <year> as arguments, like `python script.py December 2013`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianTernus I managed to get it work when calling from csv, however I am not sure my attempt at calling the script in python is on the right tracks or not. I have added the code that I tried. Many thanks GTPE

Comment: I have added a bounty to this question. Mainly because I appreciate the help you have given me with regards to solving this issue. If no one else answers the remaining issue I will award it to you anyways at the end of the 7 days. However In case you do get time. There was one final issue with regards to calling the script from python. See edits question. Many thanks GTPE

Comment: I think you need to split the filename: it should probably be `['python', 'RawDataSheetMergerPandasTest.py', 'September', '2013']`. Also, add `shell=True` to the command line to make it find `python`.

Also also: I think all the sweet "next month" code I wrote is unnecessary for your use case :)

Comment: Thanks works perfectly now. Will award bounty once hours has elapsed. Thanks GTPE

Comment: @GTPE So, about that :)

Comment: Yep brilliant, thanks for the code it has been used in several places by me now. Was a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in`os.path.commonprefix`function which accepts any number of input files:

```
import os

filenames = ['data csv 1\September 2013 1 UUedit1.csv',
             'data csv 1\September 2013 2 UUedit2.csv',]

merged_filename = os.path.commonprefix(filenames).rstrip(' ') + ' MRG.csv'
print repr(merged_filename)  # --> 'data csv 1\September 2013 MRG.csv'
```